# How can I define a space-efficient 8-byte structure in C++ for storing two types of information?

Tags: c++, definition

I am trying to define a structure that is 8 bytes large. The structure has to be space efficient since we will have millions of these and the amount of memory we use for it is at a premium.

The structure may contain 2 different kinds of information based on the type.

Defining them in the way below makes it 8 bytes - I am assuming that the `address` becomes 8 bytes since it is defined as a struct. Is there a good clean way to achieve this? I could remove the internal struct and union and define it as a 62-bit field and then cast it as necessary in the code but I was trying to avoid doing that.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct Record{
    union {
        struct {
            uint64_t     offset:48;
            uint16_t     len:14;         
        } address;

        uint64_t  opaque:62;
    } recInfo;

    uint8_t      recType:2;      // Indicates the type of the record
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Why not just compute this manually? If I saw a structure like this in some C code I was tasked with maintaining I'd want to get rid of it the moment I saw it. Bitfields are always way more trouble than they're worth due to endian issues. Use bitmasks and simple math that's easy to test.

Comment: This looks like little more than `offset << 48 | len` which is a *lot* less code.

Comment: Bitfields are no guarantee you will use as little bits as possible.

Comment: Do note that type punning through a union like this has undefined behavior.

Comment: Use either `std::uint64_t` or `std::byte[8]` as the backing store, and do your own bit twiddling to extract/store the data using getters/setters.

Comment: You can convert the 8 byte object to the other 8 byte object using ``std::bit_cast` w/o UB and just avoid unions. Also, you can use bit fields but know that the storage sequence is implementation defined so if you do you should also validate the order you expect using `static_assert` to produce an error if the sequence changes in the future. Better to shift and mask..

Comment: Actually, I don't mean to do type punning. The information in each instance of `recInfo` will **always** be accessed via only one of `address` or `opaque`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than messing around with bit fields, you can store the data in one type, and provide member functions to access it.

```
class Record {
    uint64_t data;
public:

    struct Address {
        uint64_t offset;
        uint16_t len;         
    };

    uint64_t opaque() const { return data >> 2; }
    void opaque(uint64_t value) { data = (value << 2) | OpaqueMarker; }
    Address address() const { return { data >> 16, (data >> 2) & 0x4FFF }; }
    void address(Address value) { data = (value.offset << 16) | (value.len << 2) | OffsetMarker;     
    uint8_t recType() const { return data & 0x3; }
};
```

Comment: There is no indication in the question that type-punning is involved. The question is entirely consistent with storing different types of data at different times and not treating one type as another.